# How to tell Matlab to choose "plain-matlab-code" version of a function instead of mex version?

Tags: matlab, mex

In my code, I have some compiled mex files. For compatibility reasons, I also have "plain" matlab code that returns the same things. 
The idea is that if the user don't have the right version of the mex files, the code should still be able to run with the plain matlab version. It will be slower, but it should run.
The advantage is that matlab will automatically choose the plain matlab version if the right mex file is not present.

Now, my question si the following : is it possible to tell matlab to use, at some point, the "plain" version, even if the right mex file *is* present ? This is mostly for performances comparaisons.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: can't you just put the mex files in one folder and the non-mex files in another and add either the mex-folder or the non-mex folder to MATLABs path?

Comment: If they're in the same folder, no. The MEX function always takes [precedence](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html) over the `*.m` function. Your only option is to [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) into a folder with the desired version of the script/function and execute it. You need to ensure that neither folder is in [MATLAB's path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html).

Comment: ok, thanks to both of you. I guess I'll need to either play with the folders, or rename the functions.